# gedit + sshfs won't save (vi saves fine!)

Tags: permissions, gedit, sshfs

I mounted a remote directory using `sshfs` and I can't save files using `gedit`, while saving same file using `vi` works. Changin permission to `o-r (640)` allows `gedit` to save files OK. Is there a way to change `sshfs` connection to make `gedit` work without `chmod`ding every file?

(I use -o uid=`id -u` -o gid=`id -g`, so that remote files seem to be owned by me)

```
$ touch test.txt 
[!] test.txt appears

$ vi test.txt 
[!] :wq -> saves just FINE

$ gedit test.txt 
[!] opens fine, but upon save shows "You do not have the 
[!] permissions necessary to save the file" error - 
[!] CAN'T SAVE

$ vi test.txt 
[!] edit, :wq -> again saves just FINE!

$ ls -l test.txt
-rw-r--r-- ..... test.txt

[!] Now the tricky part:

$ chmod o-r test.txt
-rw-r----- ..... test.txt  <-- removed 'read' perm. from 'others'
$ gedit test.txt 
# WORKS! Saves just fine!
```

Why removing read permission from others allows gedit to save? (while vi and the rest doesn't have that problem?)

Is there a way to change sshfs connection string to allow me to edit all files directly on server, without having to chmod o-r them?

Answer (score 5):

`-o workaround=rename` solved my problem

Answer (score 3):

The workaround on gedit 2.30.4/Ubuntu 11.04 seems to be *enabling* the "Create a backup copy..." in Preferences, not disabling it. At least for me, this worked without having to modify any permissions.

This also works in Debian sid with gedit 3.4.2

Comment: It's decidedly an odd workaround, but it definitely works.

Answer (score 2):

`-o allow_other` might do something for you...seems like someone had a similar problem here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=873199

Comment: It asks for /etc/fuse.conf, but I don't want to run sshfs via sudo. -o workaround=rename seems to have solved my problem, any particular reason why -o allow_other is better than workaround=rename ?

Comment: Tried `-o allow_other` - didn't help.

Comment: `-o allow_other` is a sshfs option

Answer (score 1):

Append `-o allow_other` to the end of your mount instruction.

[EDIT]
This is a known issue, I found a bug report at https://bugs.launchpad.net/gedit/+bug/34813 .

Also found that you can work around the bug from within gedit (at least) by disabling the 
`Create a backup copy of files before saving` option, in `Edit`->`Preferences`->`Editor`.

The issue (according to the gedit guys) is a samba/cifs bug, and was first logged (in Ubuntu) in 2006.

Comment: Tried. Didn't help. workaround=rename helped

Comment: Yes, I noticed your other comment. I've been trying to duplicate your 'issue', and can't. I always manage to save the file using gedit. So I'm wondering what the file permissions are on the actual server of the directory you're trying to write into? I'm trying to understand WHY removing the read permission for others works, not just the workaround.

Comment: With plain sshfs server-side permissions are `-rw-r--r--` (`644` I guess). 644 won't allow to save file, `.goutstreamer-...` file appears and isn't removed while saving. If I change perms to `640` - saves fine and `.gout...` file doesn't appear. I guess gedit saves data to `.gout..` file, then renames it and 644 somehow prevents rename.

Comment: by `.gout..` files I mean something like `.goutputstream-W7PGMV`

Comment: Oh, sorry, you need to have `-o uid="id -u" -o gid="id -g"` (change double quotes to backticks) in sshfs for chmod 640 to work. (Without -o uid, -o gid, changing perms to 640 doesn't do anything - gedit still can't save)

Comment: Okay some googling. Seems it's a known issue with gedit and sshfs. Seems to be a samba/cifs issue. Gedit is not the only application affected. Disabling "Create a backup copy of files before saving" apparantly cures it from within gedit too (in Edit->Preferences->Editor). 
Read https://bugs.launchpad.net/gedit/+bug/34813 for the exciting history of this bug (since march 2006!)

Answer (score 0):

```
sshfs -o allow_other,default_permissions -o IdentityFile=/path/to/ssh_key  REMOTE_USERNAME@REMOTE_HOST:/remote/dir/path/ test_mnt/
```

Adding default_permissions does the trick!